# Xpath - need help in extracting a value

Tags: xml, xpath

For the below HTML content, could someone please help me to extract price(Price2) which comes right after the node label and which has attribute checked="true".
Sample HTML content:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="left">
<input type="radio" data-max-per-order="12" data-out-of-stock="0" data-purchasable="1" data-product-id="29391" data-product-option-id="24501" name="type" class="product-option" id="product_option_radio_for-24501" />3 doses</label>
</td>
<td id="per_pound_for_24501" class="right">
<span class="competitor">
$10.65
</span>
</td>
<td class="ships-free"> </td>
<td data-price="price1" id="price_for_24501" class="right">$Price1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="left">
<input type="radio" data-max-per-order="12" data-out-of-stock="0" data-purchasable="1" data-product-id="29391" data-product-option-id="24688" name="type" class="product-option" id="product_option_radio_for-24688" checked="true" />Some Text</label>
</td>
<td id="per_pound_for_24688" class="right">
<span class="competitor">
$8.99
</span>
</td>
<td class="ships-free"> <div>SHIPS <br /> FREE!</div></td>
<td data-price="Price2" id="price_for_24688" class="right">$Price2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What value you want to extract exactly, `$Price2` or `$8.99`?

Comment: $price2..
<td data-price="Price2" id="price_for_24688" class="right">$Price2</td>

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are many different XPath to do the same, one example :

```
//tr[
      td//input[@checked='true'] 
    ]
/td[@data-price]
```